# Generate SQL scripts in powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I want to be able to generate simple repetitive scripts in SQL using Powershell as the scripting language.
For example,  If I want to generate a SQL GRANT command for every table in a database, and for every category of user in the database,  the generic grant command might look like this:

```
grant $privs 
   on $table 
   to $user;
```

Here, $privs, $table, and $user are parameters to the Grant command,  expressed as powershell variables.

I want to step through a list of data that could be applied to this generic form to produce the actual script.  The list of data might look like this:

```
privs       table       user                
-----       -----       ----                
ALL         Employees   DBA                 
READ        Employees   Analyst             
READ, WRITE Employees   Application         
ALL         Departments DBA                 
READ        Departments Analyst, Application
```

This should generate five SQL GRANT commands.

Full Disclosure:  I am asking this question so as to be able to provide my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a little function in Powershell that applies a driver table to a template in order to produce a simple repetitive result.  It was really a learning exercise to help me become proficient in Powershell.

Here is the function:

```
 <#
.NOTES
    Script: Expand-Csv    Rev:  3.2
    By:     DGC           Date: 2-21-19
.SYNOPSIS
    Generates multiple expansions of a template,
    driven by data in a CSV file.
.DESCRIPTION
    This function is a table driven template tool. 

    It generates output from a template and
    a driver table.  The template file contains plain
    text and embedded variables.  The driver table 
    (in a csv file) has one column for each variable, 
    and one row for each expansion to be generated.
#>
function Expand-csv {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
       [string] $driver,
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
       [string] $template
    )
    Process {
       Import-Csv $driver | % {
           $_.psobject.properties | % {Set-variable -name $_.name -value $_.value}
           Get-Content $template | % {$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_)} 
       }
    }
}
```

Expand-Csv takes two inputs.  The first is a CSV file that represents the driver table.  In this  example,  the csv file might look like this.

```
privs,table,user
ALL,Employees,DBA
READ,Employees,Analyst
"READ, WRITE", Employees, Application
ALL,Departments,DBA
READ,Departments,"Analyst, Application"
```

The template might look like this:

```
grant $privs 
   on $table 
   to $user;
```

The result of running it through Expand-Csv might look like this:

```
grant ALL 
   on Employees 
   to DBA;


grant READ 
   on Employees 
   to Analyst;


grant READ, WRITE 
   on Employees 
   to Application;


grant ALL 
   on Departments 
   to DBA;


grant READ 
   on Departments 
   to Analyst, Application;
```

This result is fed down the pipeline,  but it could easily be written to a file for later execution by SQL.

A superior tool might be written that takes as input a table or view in a database instead of a .CSV file.  I wanted to do the easy stuff first.

I apologize for the fact that the code is not easy to read.  I was interested in minimizing the use of variables inside it,  so I used $_ in more than one context.  At least it's small.

You may be able to use this tool as a starting point to develop something that will make your workload easier.  I hope so.